# How to add an input to the admin customer account info form in Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, customer-account

In Magento 1.9 there's this form in the magento admin:

[image: account info]

What's the best way to add an additional checkbox input to this form? I need this new checkbox/flag to be saved to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are the best bet for this job. Below script will help you to add an additional checkbox in the customer form

Create a script add.php in your root folder and use the below script, and call this script http://domain.com/add.php

```
<?php
 $baseDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));

 require_once($baseDir.'/app/Mage.php');

 umask(0);
 Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

 $installer = new Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup('core_setup');
 $installer->startSetup();

 $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

 $entityTypeId     = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer');
 $attributeSetId   = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
 $attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, 
 $attributeSetId);


 $installer->addAttribute('customer', 'additional_checkbox', array(
    'label' => 'Additional Checkox',
    'visible'  => true,
    'input' => 'checkbox',
    'type'  => 'int',
    'source'  => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table',
    'forms' => array('adminhtml_customer'),
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 0,
));

$attribute  = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", 
"additional_checkbox");

$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
   $entityTypeId,
   $attributeSetId,
   $attributeGroupId,
   'additional_checkbox',
   '99991'  //sort_order
 );

 //$used_in_forms=array();

 $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";

 $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
   ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
   ->setData("is_system", 0)
   ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
   ->setData("is_visible", 1)
   ->setData("sort_order", 100)
 ;
 $attribute->save();
 $installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but thanks. So when I run this script it just adds some data to the database and I can then throw away the script? Should I make a module that contains this code? Where is the best documentation to learn about all the stuff you used in your code?

Comment: The right place for this code is setup folder in a module mysql4-install-1.0.0.php. This will run only once, at the time of module installation.

Comment: read more https://www.sitepoint.com/magento-install-upgrade-data-scripts-explained/

Comment: Why do you have to specify the forms twice?

Comment: @Ryan That is an error from my side